# <select> height won't expand to 100% in IE7/8

Tags: html, css

I need my site to be able to support IE7/8 and I'm having problems setting the height of an input.

In IE9 the input stretches to 100% of the parents height but in IE8/7 I have tried everything to expand the height of the input with no luck.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="element">
    <select name="searchType" class="select">
        <option value="title">Title</option>
        <option value="author">Author</option>
        <option value="isbn">ISBN</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.element {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}
div.element select {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:none;
    padding:2px;
}
div.element input[type=text] {
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    border:none;
    padding:5px;
}
```

**jsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/GvX5x/1/

**What IE7 looks like:**

[image]

**What IE9 looks like:**

[image]

Comment: Where does `input[type="text"]` come into the equation?

Comment: @Connor Sorry, ignore that.

Comment: The only difference I notice in IE 7/8 is that the text is at the bottom of the select, rather than vertically centered (in IE 9/10). Perhaps you want something that simulates `line-height:100%`?

Comment: @trojansdestroy no it didn't make a difference, I want the dropdown height to be the same height as the .element div container

Comment: I think if there would be a `line-height` defined in body tag or any other parent element of `select` tag then it's not going to let the `select` to be expanded.

Comment: @mk_89 The select height matches the height of `div.element` in IE 7+ for me with your current code. Do you mean you want the box that actually drops down to be that height?

Comment: @trojansdestroy I've edited the OP, take a look at the images, there is a difference in the height.

Comment: @mk_89 Are you using IE10's dev tools to change browser mode? If so, when you change to lower than IE10, the "Document Mode" setting automatically changes to IE5 Quirks, and the result is what your pictures show. Set that to match the correct version of IE's standards mode and it returns to normal

Comment: @trojansdestroy Yes, I'm using IE dev tools, I always make sure to match the browser mode with the document mode. It's strange that you can't see the same thing as me.

Comment: Something else must be affecting it then. Do you have more code?

Comment: @trojansdestroy I don't know id you want to go down that road, the site is still under construction but the link is http://www.bookdb.co.uk

Comment: I don't think there's a code-related answer here. [Here's a screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OyEST.jpg) of your live site in IE 7-10. I have no idea why we aren't seeing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

All browsers have their own way of displaying the input, select elements etc. 
May i suggest you to have a look on the **[Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)** jQuery plugin which changes the appearance of the select tag? 
This way (if you have a custom made select for example) you will be sure that it will look exactly the same on all browsers and versions.

Answer (score -1):

its easy note this:

Internet Explorer:

```
TagOrID , * html TagOrId , *+html TagOrId {
        margin: 14em; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera*/
        margin: 15.3em\9; /*IE*/
        margin: 15.3em\0/; /*IE*/
}
```

open your site in IE and define just for IE your CSS!

Comment: margin is just a example!